# Nuxt vue-router beforeRouteLeave navigation guard cause maximum call stack size exceeded when I check if to.hash is empty

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-i18n

I'm stuck with a loop problem that I think shouldn't have reasons to happen.
In a Nuxt nested dynamic page component (_id.vue), I want to check if `to.hash` is not empty in a `beforeRouteLeave` navigation guard but when I do this check and it is true, I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I did a test with `console.log('test')` and I saw it was called non-stop until the browser stops it before to prevent it to crash.

```
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    // there is hash and if the user click the back button of the browser, I want to return him to the position of the product file where he was before the click to enter into it
    if (to.name.startsWith('index___') && to.hash !== '') {
      next({ path: to.path, hash: `#${this.$route.params.id}` })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
```

This only happens if I test for `to.hash !== ''` but not for `to.hash === '#ct'` and I can't understand why?

If the user comes from the index page with a hash in the path, if he clicks the browser's back button, I want to brings him back to the position in the page where he was when he clicked to browse to the `_id` page.

Can someone helps me please to understand what's happening here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer that helped me in [Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/when-i-check-if-to-hash-is-empty-in-beforerouteleave-navigation-guard-of-vue-router-it-causes-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-infinite-loop/103869/2?u=jeckojim), I didn't know that `next()` was recalling the process and that my `beforeRouteLeave` hook  was reevaluating the new `to.hash` I setted causing the loop (`to.hash !== ''` was always true).

Be sure to test a value to the opposite that will pass the condition after you set it the 1rst time.

here's the code to fix the problem:

```
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if (to.name.startsWith('index___') && (to.hash === '#ct' | (to.hash !== `#${this.$route.params.id}` && to.hash !== ''))) {
      next({ path: to.path, hash: `#${this.$route.params.id}` })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
```

I hope it can help someone else.